# CSS Floating expandable menu to display content

Tags: html, css, menu, floating

Please by kind to me as I'm a noob. I've created a page in html but now I need to do something I think html can't do. On the left hand side I'm looking to create a floating menu that expands. This would be vertical. When you click on the 1st option, it would expand with instructions, then you can close it. Then one might jump down to the 4th. All the while, there will be a main html map (which is already done) in the middle where they can try what is in the instructions. I'm COMPLETELY new to CSS. I've found something similar to what I want, but not quite.

```
    <style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
     }

    ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 15%;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
position: fixed;
height: 50%;
overflow: auto;
    }

    li a {
display: inline;
color: #000;
padding: 8px 0 8px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
    }

    li a.active {
background-color: #4CAF50;
color: white;
    }

    li a:hover:not(.active) {
background-color: #555;
color: white;
    }
    </style>

    <body>

    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="home.htm">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#one.htm">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#two.htm">TWo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Three.htm">Three</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div style="margin-left:15%;padding:1px 16px;height:1000px;">
    <img src="image.png" width="1200" height="900" usemap="#map" /> 

    <map name="map">

    </map>
    </div>

    </body>
```

I might be completely off on this. I'm starting to study CSS so I can understand this more. Any and all suggestions would be great. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is an accordion menu.

If you want to use pure CSS, you need to use CSS transitions. Did a quick Google search and found a simple example: 
http://bradsknutson.com/blog/css-only-accordion/

If you don't mind using a bit of Javascript then jQuery UI has a quick and easy to use accordion menu, you can choose different options(e.g. sortable menu etc). You might have to learn the jQuery setup basics if you haven't used jQuery UI before.
https://jqueryui.com/accordion/#sortable